# Regex for image src Tags that has nothing inside it

Tags: python, regex

I want to Extract from image src tag Likes

```
<img src=''/>
<img src=""/>
<img src="" alt="" id="75eb500af82b4f0c9e9006539f12163b " />
..
```

so i use this regex

```
<img src=(""|'').*?/>
```

Not working..

Comment: There is nothing to extract in src attribute. Can you post some realistic examples?

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to parse HTML via regexp - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 (https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  Anyways why don't use simply use for src `src=(".*"|'.*')`?

Comment: Without knowledge of which regex implementation you are using, it's trivially possible that you are using one which doesn't support `.*?` for example.  This is why you should also specify which tool or language you are using, and tag your question accordingly. See also the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi i don't want to extract normal img tags. I want to remove useless img tags within some html codes like I posted.

Comment: @pakachu: I've updated my answer to provide a regex that will match img tags where src attribute doesn't contain any text inside. Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any other queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although parsing html with regex is highly discouraged, but since this is a  case of `<img` tags which doesn't have nesting, you can use this regex to find all img tags where src tag doesn't contain anything inside it.

```
<img\s+src=(['"])\1.*?>
```

**Explanation:**

- `<img\s+` --> matches `<img` tag literally followed by one or more whitespace
- `src= -->` matches src= literally
- `(['"]) -->` Matches either a single quote or double quote
- `\1` --> Matches either singlequote or doublequote depending upon whatever actually matched
- `.*?>` --> Followed by any character zero or more times in non-greedy way followed by literal > character denoting end of img tag

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWQbWi/3)

Also, in your own original regex, everything was fine except one thing, where you needed to escape / character in the end. You should have written,

```
<img src=(""|'').*?\/>
```

instead of,

```
<img src=(""|'').*?/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. with your help, i found properly regex i wanted.                                   "<img\s+src=['\"]['\"].*?/>" it works

Comment: Great. I would suggest you to tag your post with the language too you are working in, so we can help you with sample codes also in that language.